# Método para editar dados com Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um gestor de ficheiros e já implementei alguns métodos como `addArquivo`, `listarArquivo`, `listarVersoes`, etc.

Porém preciso editar o mesmo, vejam meus métodos do DAL:

Adicionar:

```
 internal void AddArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
            ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = Util.Util.GUIDs.GetGUID(),
                    ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                    DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                    TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
                },
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arquivo.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arquivo.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Obter um arquivo:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Método que busca um arquivo conforme parametro
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="termo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal Arquivo GetArquivo(string termo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var arquivo = (from arq in ctx.ARQUIVO
                           where arq.ARQUIVO_GUID == termo
                           || arq.XARQUIVO == termo
                           select new Arquivo()
                           {
                               ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                               DIRETORIO_GUID = arq.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                               EXTENSAO = arq.EXTENSAO,
                               IS_STREAM = arq.IS_STREAM,
                               TAG = arq.TAG,
                               TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arq.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                               ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arq.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                               URL = arq.URL,
                               XARQUIVO = arq.XARQUIVO,
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
            arquivo.ArquivoVersoes.Add(GetArquivoVersao(arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID));
            return arquivo;
        }
    }
```

Mapeamento:

```
    public DbSet<ARQUIVO> ARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ARQUIVO_PRODUTO> ARQUIVO_PRODUTO { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ARQUIVO_VERSAO> ARQUIVO_VERSAO { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DIRETORIO> DIRETORIO { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DIRETORIO_PASTA> DIRETORIO_PASTA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO> TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO { get; set; }
```

O que eu fiz com ajuda da resposta do Thiago Custodio:

```
internal void UpdateArquivo(String termo, Arquivo arquivoEditado)
    {

        var arquivo = GetArquivo(termo);
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {



            arquivo.XARQUIVO = arquivoEditado.XARQUIVO;
            arquivo.TAG = arquivoEditado.TAG;
            arquivo.EXTENSAO = arquivoEditado.EXTENSAO;
            arquivo.URL = arquivoEditado.URL;
            arquivo.IS_STREAM = arquivoEditado.IS_STREAM;

            ctx.Entry(arquivo).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

    }
    }
```

Porem ta dando essa exception:

```
the entity type arquivo not part of the model for the current context
```

Comment: Já percebeu que suas perguntas sempre precisam ser editadas? Dê uma olhada, procure melhorar. Você está recebendo grande ajuda aqui no *site* ajude-nos manter tudo organizado, evite dar trabalho extra para os outros usuários que te ajudam. Especialmente cuidado para colocar *tags*, quase sempre usar uma existente é melhor que criar outra, especialmente com o nome errado. Programar exige cuidado. Cuidado se obtêm treinando em tudo na vida.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou tentar melhorar.

Comment: @WarLock, antes de começar a trabalhar com uma ferramenta, tente conhecer a mesma primeiro, vejo que está tentando utilizar o EF, sem ter o menor conhecimento do seu funcionamento. Neste caso te aconselho ler o seguinte artigo: http://www.macoratti.net/10/11/c_efcrud.htm

Comment: @TobyMosque atualizei a pergunta, com o que tentei com a ajuda do amigo thiago, valeu pelo link tenho que estudar, mas ver o que pode me ajudar no momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui usando da forma seguinte:

```
internal void UpdateArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivoEditado)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var file = ctx.ARQUIVO.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoEditado.ARQUIVO_GUID);
            if (file == null)
                throw new ArquivoException("Arquivo não encontrado");

            file.XARQUIVO = arquivoEditado.XARQUIVO;
            file.TAG = arquivoEditado.TAG;
            file.EXTENSAO = arquivoEditado.EXTENSAO;
            file.URL = arquivoEditado.URL;
            file.IS_STREAM = arquivoEditado.IS_STREAM;

            ctx.Entry(file).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Foi so usar o :

```
 var file = ctx.ARQUIVO.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ARQUIVO_GUID == arquivoEditado.ARQUIVO_GUID);
```

que assim ele pegava exatamente o arquivo que eu queria editar, mas obrigado a todos.

Comment: no lugar de usar o .FirstOrDefault(), utilize o .Find(), pois o mesmo tem um nome mais apropriado para esta situação e é cerca de duas vezes mais rapido.

Comment: poderia entrar no seguinte chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70597/mvc-wcf-e-entity-framework

Comment: Vou entrar, galera de .net?

Comment: brasileiro?....

Comment: tinha criado este canal para tentar te dá algumas dicas.

Comment: se puder entrar la agora

Answer (score 0):

algo assim:

```
var termo = "";
var arquivo = GetArquivo(termo);

arquivo.TAG  = "outra tag";

using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
{
    ctx.Entry(arquivo).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: esse outra tag seria o q?

Comment: voce colocou arquivo.tag , como exemplo de q? da alteração de um dado? no caso eu teria que alterar todos os atributos?

Comment: uma propriedade da sua classe Arquivo, não!?

Comment: vc pode setar qualquer prop que vc queira alterar...dei só este exemplo de como alterar a propriedade TAG.

Comment: eu sei, mas no caso eu teria que fazer em todas as propriedades setadas neh?

Comment: mas tipo, ai esta manual neh, qual seria a melhor forma de editar o que o usuario passou?

Comment: eu teria que trazer do cliente, um objeto com tudo ja setado neh?]

Comment: vou testar aqui e te retorno valeu

Comment: ta dando essa exception: The entity type Arquivo is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: sabe o que pode ser?